# c++ include a header file that contains an include to this header file

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I have a header file called `X.h` that contains `#include "y.h"`, and a header file called `Y.h` that I need to `#include "X.h"` in, but when I do I get errors on everything in class `Y`. I assume because header Y has failed.

I have added `#pragma once`. When I remove this, I get too many include files: depth = 1204 error, so that doesn't work either.

Is there a way around this issue?

The reason I haven't included the header files is because they are standard header files with a class in them.

The only notable point is that `X.h` contains an array outside the class so that the array is outside the stack, and on the heap so that it can be bigger than 8mb.

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

X.h

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;
#include "y.h"
static unique_ptr<Y> y[5][5];
class X{}
```

Y.h

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;
#include "X.h" <- I want this but it causes the errors.
class Y{}
```

Comment: please show a [mre] and include the full error message

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: imagine you were the preprocessor, what would you do to expand that circular inclusion?  Usually there's a flaw with  that kind of design, but you can get away with it if it's a recursive data structure, etc., and the  usual solution is a declaration  of  a type as  incomplete.  Or factor out what  they share to header z.h and they both include it.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the code, but i can't include the errors because literally everything breaks because the header file breaks there are 45 errors that cover everything in the cpp file because it relies on the header file.

Comment: @DavidBenz You have a circular reference between `X.h` and `Y.h`.  The solution to break that is to use **forward declarations** instead of includes.

Comment: @DavidBenz generally you only need to pay attention to the first error in the output log.

Comment: I did try header.z approach and have it kind of setup for another issue but it causes an error with the static array. If that is the only approach then i'll have to try fixing that then.

Comment: Ill also look into forward includes.

Comment: @DavidBenz There is no such thing as "forward includes". I said ["forward declarations"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Forward_declaration).

Comment: "I want this but it causes the errors" Why do you want to include X.h?